# cakephp authenticate with ldap and match to local user (or create one)

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, ldap, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to configure ldap authentication on cakephp 3.8 using the new [cakephp/authentication](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication) plugin, and I'm not sure how to match the authenticated ldap user with a local entity.

My config closely follows the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/index.html) and is available in full [here](https://github.com/waspinator/cakephp-quickstart/).

in my `Application.php` the `Application` class implements both the `AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface` and the `AuthorizationServiceProviderInterface`

```
public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request, 
                                         ResponseInterface $response)
{
    $service = new AuthenticationService();
    $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [...]),
    $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Ldap', [
        'fields' => [
           'username' => 'username',
           'password' => 'password'
        ],
        'host' => 'ldap.forumsys.com',
        'port' => '389',
        'bindDN' => function($username) {
                return 'uid='.$username.',DC=example,DC=com';
            },
        'options' => [LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION => 3]
    ]);

    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email', 
                'password' => 'password'
             ],
            'loginUrl' => '/users/login'
    ]);

    return $service;
}
```

In my middleware, I'm trying decorate the identity with authorization stuff. When authenticating using the regular local system the `$identity` is a `App\Model\Entity\User`, but when logging in with a ldap user it's a `Authentication\Identity`

So when I call `setAuthorization`

```
'identityDecorator' => function (AuthorizationServiceInterface $authorization, 
                                 ArrayAccess $identity) {
    $identity->setAuthorization($authorization);
}
```

it fails with a `Call to undefined method Authentication\Identity::setAuthorization()` since all I have in `$identity` is

```
object(Authentication\Identity) {

    'config' => [
        'fieldMap' => [
            'id' => 'id'
        ]
    ],
    'data' => object(ArrayObject) {
        username => 'einstein'
    }

}
```

How would I match an authenticated ldap user with their local counterpart, and transform from `Authentication\Identity` to `App\Model\Entity\User`?

The final goal is to also optionally generate local users from ldap data if they don't exist.

---

middleware attempt

`Application.php`

```
public function middleware($middlewareQueue)
{
    ...

    $middlewareQueue->add($authentication);
    $middlewareQueue->add($ldap_matcher);
    $middlewareQueue->add($authorization);

    return $middlewareQueue;
}
```

`LdapMatcherMiddleware.php`

```
class LdapMatcherMiddleware
{
    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, 
                             ResponseInterface $response, $next)
    {
        $identity = $request->getAttribute('identity');

        if ($identity !== null) {
            $identity = $this->buildIdentity($identity);
            $request = $request->withAttribute('identity', $identity);
        }

        $response = $next($request, $response);

        return $response;
    }

    public function buildIdentity($identity)
    {
        $Users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');

        $username = $identity->getOriginalData()['username'];
        $user = $Users->find()->where(['username' => $username])->first();

        if (is_null($identity)) {
            $user = $this->createLocalUserFromLdap($identity);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function createLocalUserFromLdap($identity)
    {
        $Users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');

        $user = $Users->newEntity([
            'username' => $identity->getOriginalData()['username']
        ]);

        $Users->save($user);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would I match an authenticated ldap user with their local counterpart, and transform from Authentication\Identity to App\Model\Entity\User?

I would add another middleware after the authentication middleware and do that step there.

```
$users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');
$entity = $users->newEntity($identity->getOriginalData());
```

Then do whatever you need to do for authorization with this entity.

> The final goal is to also optionally generate local users from ldap data if they don't exist.

Just implement your logic somewhere and get the entity the same way as shown above from the identity.

```
$users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');
$entity = $users->newEntity($identity->getOriginalData());
// Check if it exists inside this method and if not just create it
$users->createLocalUserFromLDAP($entity);
```

Comment: I added some middleware, but I'm not sure how to update the `_data` property of `Authentication\Authenticator\Result`. When logging in with a local user it's of type `App\Model\Entity\User`, but after adding the ldap_matcher it's still just an `ArrayObject`.